# Using the CryptoPP vectors in the GCM sample code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, encryption, vector, crypto++

I have downloaded the CryptoPP library and I am able to run the sample codes and get results (for CCM and GCM modes).

The next step for me is to try out the test vectors for each of these modes. From my understanding im suppose to try out the different keys, IVs and plaintexts as specified in the test vectors. Then I have to verify that the expected results are also specified in each vector.

What I can seem to understand is how to input these keys and IVs for the vectors. From the code as shown below, it seems to be using a random key.

Preferably I would like to input the keys and IVs from command prompt and then run the test code. Just setting the vectors from the code in Visual Studio would do though.

Please find the sample code and one of the vectors below:

Sample Code:

```
AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

SecByteBlock key( AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH );
prng.GenerateBlock( key, key.size() );

byte iv[ AES::BLOCKSIZE * 16 ];
prng.GenerateBlock( iv, sizeof(iv) );    

const int TAG_SIZE = 12;

// Plain text
string pdata="Authenticated Encryption";

// Encrypted, with Tag
string cipher, encoded;

// Recovered plain text
string rpdata;

/*********************************\
\*********************************/

try
{
    GCM< AES >::Encryption e;
    e.SetKeyWithIV( key, key.size(), iv, sizeof(iv) );

    StringSource( pdata, true,
        new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter( e,
            new StringSink( cipher ), false, TAG_SIZE
        ) // AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter
    ); // StringSource
}
catch( CryptoPP::Exception& e )
{
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    exit(1);
}

/*********************************\
\*********************************/

try
{
    GCM< AES >::Decryption d;
    d.SetKeyWithIV( key, key.size(), iv, sizeof(iv) );

    AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter df( d,
        new StringSink( rpdata ),
        DEFAULT_FLAGS, TAG_SIZE
    ); // AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter

    // The StringSource dtor will be called immediately
    //  after construction below. This will cause the
    //  destruction of objects it owns. To stop the
    //  behavior so we can get the decoding result from
    //  the DecryptionFilter, we must use a redirector
    //  or manually Put(...) into the filter without
    //  using a StringSource.
    StringSource( cipher, true,
        new Redirector( df /*, PASS_EVERYTHING */ )
    ); // StringSource

    // If the object does not throw, here's the only
    //  opportunity to check the data's integrity
    if( true == df.GetLastResult() ) {
        cout << "recovered text: " << rpdata << endl;
    }
}
catch( CryptoPP::Exception& e )
{
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

One of the vectors:

```
GCM Test Case #14 (AES-256)
Variable          Value
-------------------------------------------------
K               : 00000000000000000000000000000000
                : 00000000000000000000000000000000
P               : 00000000000000000000000000000000
IV              : 000000000000000000000000
H               : dc95c078a2408989ad48a21492842087
Y_0             : 00000000000000000000000000000001
E(K,Y_0)        : 530f8afbc74536b9a963b4f1c4cb738b
Y_1             : 00000000000000000000000000000002
E(K,Y_1)        : cea7403d4d606b6e074ec5d3baf39d18
X_1             : fd6ab7586e556dba06d69cfe6223b262
len(A)||len(C)  : 00000000000000000000000000000080
GHASH(H,A,C)    : 83de425c5edc5d498f382c441041ca92
C               : cea7403d4d606b6e074ec5d3baf39d18

T               : d0d1c8a799996bf0265b98b5d48ab919
```

Comment: I guess you will have to parse the file and know how to handle a hexadecimal decoder. We are not going to write this code for you; please show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply...I never asked you to write my code...i just didnt know how to move foward..now that you have mentioned  "parse the file" and "how to handle a hexadecimal decoder" I will try to connect the dots..thank you

Comment: If you have any specific questions or if you don't understand what parameter should be put where, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have downloaded the CryptoPP library and I am able to run the sample codes and get results (for CCM and GCM modes).

Crypto++ does not use the examples from its wiki when running its self tests. The self test code is much more hairier.

> What I can seem to understand is how to input these keys and IVs for the vectors. From the code as shown below, it seems to be using a random key.

The Crypto++ test vectors are located in `<crypto++ dir>/TestVectors`. I don't believe the vector you show in your question is from Crypto++. For example, here's from `<crypto++ dir>/TestVectors/gcm.txt`:

```
AlgorithmType: AuthenticatedSymmetricCipher
Name: AES/GCM
Source: aes-modes-src-07-10-08/Testvals/gcm.1, Basic Tests for GCM (compiled by B. R. Gladman)
Key: 00000000000000000000000000000000
IV:  000000000000000000000000
MAC: 00000000000000000000000000000000 
Test: NotVerify
Key: 00000000000000000000000000000000
IV:  000000000000000000000000
MAC: 58e2fccefa7e3061367f1d57a4e7455a 
Test: Encrypt
Key: 00000000000000000000000000000000
IV:  000000000000000000000000
Plaintext: 00000000000000000000000000000000
Ciphertext: 0388dace60b6a392f328c2b971b2fe78
MAC: ab6e47d42cec13bdf53a67b21257bddf 
Test: Encrypt
...
```

You can see how the Crypto++ test suite consumes it when you use the `cryptest.exe v` command. The source files that execute the self tests are `validat1.cpp`, `validat2.cpp` and `validat3.cpp`. The GCM testing starts in `validat1.cpp` on line 95:

```
pass=ValidateGCM() && pass;
```

Here's `ValidateGCM` around line 1395:

```
bool ValidateGCM()
{
    cout << "\nAES/GCM validation suite running...\n";
    cout << "\n2K tables:";
    bool pass = RunTestDataFile("TestVectors/gcm.txt", MakeParameters(Name::TableSize(), (int)2048));
    cout << "\n64K tables:";
    return RunTestDataFile("TestVectors/gcm.txt", MakeParameters(Name::TableSize(), (int)64*1024)) && pass;
}
```

Its a real pain to untangle `RunTestDataFile`, `TestDataFile` and `TestAuthenticatedSymmetricCipher` (and friends). They are implemented in `datatest.cpp`. The pain point is `TestAuthenticatedSymmetricCipher` around line 450 of `datatest.cpp`.

I usually go to the applicable standard, pull the test vectors, and then write my own self tests. In the case of deterministic encryption like AES/GCM, you can write a Known Answer Test (KAT). For non-deterministic tests, you will need to write a Pairwise Consistency Test (PCT). Essentially, you verify you can round trip data from a public/private key pair operation, like a DH or RSA key.

Comment: hi.. i can encrypt and decrypt to get expected results.. by writing keys in my code and get my results in the command prompt..i am able to redirect my out put to a text file using freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout);
however the last bit of my work is to be able to try other vectors without keying in the keys directly in the code..i would prefer to call the text file containing the test vectors or enter the keys and iv's from command prompt..Also i tried the solution you explained above but the sample code im using from the crypto++ site is nothing like that..its not up to 1000 lines

Comment: "...i would prefer to call the text file containing the test vectors or enter the keys and iv's from command prompt" - the various vectors hex encode the parameters in vector file and hex decode the parameters after reading them. You should probably do the same. See the [HexEncoder](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexEncoder) on the Crypto++ wiki. Also, be careful of saving binary data as text. `LF` and `CR` conversions/consumptions and `NULL` terminators will produce incorrect results.

Comment: Hi..thanks! I had a look at the HexEncoder page and if i understand correctly it is used to conver string of data to hex and vice versa..however is it possible to call the textfile containing vectors from my code rather that writing vectors directly into the code..so eventually i would want to try different vectors drom command prompt with going to the IDE..Appreciate it

Comment: @user3312054 - "... is it possible to call the textfile containing vectors from my code rather that writing vectors directly into the code..." - Yes. There's lots of questions/answers on Stack Overflow fo parsing text files. See, for example, [Reading/parsing text file input c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551014/reading-parsing-text-file-input-c).