# Calling structures inside of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm currently working on a program for a basic C++ class. It involves working with structures to store and manipulate data of several baseball players. I've been progressing nicely, and I have all of my structs declared but now I've hit a roadblock.

My prompt is asking me to do the following:
*You need to parse the baseballdata.txt file and create an array of players; with all of their statistics loaded from the incoming file. The statistics include various types of primitive data elements such as float, integer, strings, booleans, and arrays. You should be able to determine the appropriate type for appropriate statistics by observing the file. Take the reference of baseballdatadescription.txt and make sure that your players have all of the statistics loaded.*

So far, I have four structs declared. One is for player information, one for offense information, one for defense information, and one struct that combines all three struts into a player_card that needs to be loaded into an array.

I've defined the player card as follows:

```
struct player_card {
    struct player;
    struct offense;
    struct defense;
};
```

The other three structs are defined as:

```
struct player {
    string name;
    string position;
    string bat_position;
    float height;
    float weight;
    string draft_team;
    bool HOF;
    float allstargame;
    float WAR;
};

struct offense {
    int hits;
    int homeruns;
    int batting_average;
    int runs;
    int runs_batted;
    int on_base_percent;
    int slugs;
    float obp_slug;
    int silver_years[5];
};

struct defense {
    int putout;
    int assists;
    int errors;
    int fielding_percent;
    int golden_years[5];
};
```

Where do I need to proceed from here to load my data into an array for 11 players?

Comment: something like [Reading/parsing text file input c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551014/reading-parsing-text-file-input-c)?

Comment: Please share more of your code so we can have a better understanding of your current state. Begin with the issue that your struct isn't seem to be well defined.

Comment: What's wrong with the simple player_card[11] = { player1, player2 ..., player11 }

Comment: I will update with my other structs

Comment: Suppose the file only contained one integer, per line, per player. Are you able to parse that kind of a file? Trying to understand what exactly you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to look at the structure of file baseballdata.txt and write code to read it to load the data from that file into memory.  You should familiarize yourself with how to read files in C++ with proper error handling and how to create objects from the file data.