# getline unreliable on macOS?

Tags: c++, c++11, getline

as a school project I have to code a video game with SDL2, imgui and SFML and I'm facing a really weird problem :

getline seems unreliable on macOS but not on linux

Let me explain, when I compile and run my code, I am able to read my configuration file properly and display the data on screen : it is working everytime on my linux computer but on my macbook it is working like 1 time out of 5.

My configuration file :[configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRmhu.png)

how the information is supposed to be displayed (working properly on linux but not everytime on macOS) : [how it is when it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtFTb.png)

The code :

```cpp
    // Récupération des derniers paramètres
    std::ifstream fichierSauvegardeR ("data/save.txt");
    if (fichierSauvegardeR.is_open())
    {
      getline(fichierSauvegardeR, strNbDes);
      strcpy(buf_nb_des, strNbDes.c_str());

      getline(fichierSauvegardeR, strNbJoueurs);
      strcpy(buf_nb_joueurs, strNbJoueurs.c_str());

      // getline(fichierSauvegardeR, strNomJoueur);
      // strcpy(noms_joueurs[0], strNomJoueur.c_str());

      for (int i = 0; i < nbJoueurs; i++) {
        if(!getline(fichierSauvegardeR, strNomJoueur))
        {
          break;
        }
        else
        {
          strcpy(noms_joueurs[i], strNomJoueur.c_str());
        }
      }
      fichierSauvegardeR.close();

    }
```

Note that, the first 2 lines of the configuration file are always properly read (even on macOS), what doesn't work is the other lines (I've tried replacing the "\n" by std::endl and it didn't changed anything)

Comment: where do you initialize `nbJoueurs` ?

Comment: Without a proper [mcve] it's impossible to say. My crystal ball tells me the `strcpy` calls are breaching the target buffer and invoking undefined behavior. I can assure you `std::getline` is *plenty* "reliable" on macOS. Soothsaying wags (wild-arse-guesses) are all you're going to get unless a proper [mcve] is provided.

Comment: You said you replaced `"\n"` with `std::endl`, but I don't see either of them in your code.

Comment: @PeterT  Well thank you I've just found out the answer because of you ! nbJoueurs was read from imgui interface so the loop code may have been executed before reading this input ? It's weird but now I'm using std::stoi(strNbJoueurs) (it is the number in the second line of my configuration file). It's still doesn't exactly work as I would want to because I want to use the number chosed by the user and not the number in the file

Comment: @WhozCraig Finally I think it is linked to imgui finally, in fact, the problem is the value of nbJoueurs which is supposed to have the valued that the user chosed on the interface

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I've tried it after copying the code, but it didn't change anything so I deleted

Comment: @Vyslon If you bothered to read [the link I provided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you'll realize what you have posted is **not** a minimal reproducible example. We cannot copy/paste/compile/run what you posted (and **only** what you posted, with *nothing else*) and reproduce your issue. *That* is the secret sauce to getting a definitive answer about code problems on this site. Without it, guesses are the best you can hope for (and all you'll receive). This isn't a question-and-guess site; it is a question and *answer* site.

Comment: `nbJoueurs` must be derived from  `buf_nb_joueurs`. Find any suitable parsing function like `sscanf`... `sscanf(buf_nb_joueurs,"%d",&nbJoueurs);` But beware, you are mixing C++-strings and C-strings, better not doing such. Stay in C++.

Answer (score -1):

Without responding to your answer (i don't have a mac for testing). I see that you use many C features. I recommend you to use "istringstream" to parse your file.

Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9551101/12374897